# Finding checkbox attributes nested in table td's using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have several checkbox fields which are nested in table td's like following:

```
<td>
    <div class="am-checkbox ChangeCheckbox">
        <input id="check20" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <label for="check10"> </label> 
     </div>
</td>
```

Now all other checkboxes have same structure as well.... Now what I'd like to do here is to trigger a click event to change the state of checkbox and check/uncheck it when it's clicked on it...

What I have done here via jQuery is like following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ChangeCheckbox", function () {
    // $('#check20').attr('checked', false);
    // console.log($(this).closest("tr"));
    // console.log($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)'));
    $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').attr('checked', false);
});
```

I'm trying to find a row which triggered the event, and then it's column #2 (eq(2)) and this is the column where the checkbox is placed...

Now the only problem here that I don't know how to solve is how do I access the input checkbox type after selected second column like following:

```
// how to select now the checkbox and set it's attribute to unchecked?
$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)')
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: @Tushar I have added it, it's in the onclick event...

Comment: why dont use class instead of finding in a row?

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').find(":checkbox").attr("checked", false)`  https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: `eq` is zero-based index. Use `eq(1)` to select second item from set. Also to change the checked state of checkbox, use `.prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes yes yes that's it , thank you so much !!! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:checkbox` pseudo-selector.  http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector

In your case, this would be:

```
$(this).closest("tr")
       .find('td:eq(2)')
       .find(":checkbox").att‌​r("checked", false);
```

---

**Edit**

To toggle, it's easiest to get the checkbox first and then just use `!` against the current value:

```
var chk = $(this).closest("tr")
                 .find('td:eq(2)')
                 .find(":checkbox");

chk.prop("checked", !chk.prop("checked"));
```

(we should be using `.prop` for checkbox checked, not `.attr`)

The next issue you'll find is that if you click the checkbox directly it doesn't change - because the checkbox *and* the tr get the click events, cancelling each out.  You'll need to cancel the tick on the checkbox.

Comment: Hey freedom, how would I now combine this with a if statement to see if the checkbox is checked, if it isn't , i'd simply uncheck it, otherwise check it?

Comment: You mean you want to toggle the value?   I was wondering why you always cleared it.  I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parents` like this:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").find('td:eq(2) > input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: `how do I access the input checkbox` - this [didn't] answer the question

Comment: Sorry @freedomn-m, I forgot to update the answer for `checkbox`. I just updated it.

Comment: Why did you change the `closest("tr")` to `parents("tr:first")`?

Comment: I am more familiar with `parents` compared to `closest`